# Using OpenCV4Tegra in ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running L4T 21.4 in TK1. I installed ROS by running the script from https://github.com/jetsonhacks/installROS. **I am trying to run opencv4tegra in ROS.** However, when I catkin_make my workspace, it show " No rule to make target `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libopencv_videostab.so.2.4.8'.
I have tried *sudo apt-get install libopencv-videostab2.4* but it remove a lot of packages including opencv4tegra and ROS. I also tried the solution from https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/835118/embedded-systems/incorrect-configuration-in-opencv4tegra-debian-packages-and-solution but still no luck.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240739/using-opencv4tegra-in-ros/) by [SamTew](https://answers.ros.org/users/23014/samtew/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

libopencv_videostab might be located in your /usr/lib folder. You should be able to bypass this issue by creating a symbolic link from the correct location of the library to /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libopencv_videostab.so.2.4.8.

I had a simular issue on the TX 1. You can create the symbolic using the following lines: (replace with your architecture and version number)

```
ln -s /usr/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4.9
ln -s /usr/lib/libopencv_contrib.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_contrib.so.2.4.9
ln -s /usr/lib/libopencv_core.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.2.4.9
ln -s /usr/lib/libopencv_detection_based_tracker.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_detection_based_tracker.so.2.4.9
ln -s /usr/lib/libopencv_esm_panorama.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_esm_panorama.so.2.4.9
ln -s /usr/lib/libopencv_facedetect.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_facedetect.so.2.4.9
ln -s /usr/lib/libopencv_features2d.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_features2d.so.2.4.9
ln -s /usr/lib/libopencv_flann.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_flann.so.2.4.9
ln -s /usr/lib/libopencv_gpu.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_gpu.so.2.4.9
ln -s /usr/lib/libopencv_highgui.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9
ln -s /usr/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.9
ln -s /usr/lib/libopencv_imuvstab.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imuvstab.so.2.4.9
ln -s /usr/lib/libopencv_legacy.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_legacy.so.2.4.9
ln -s /usr/lib/libopencv_ml.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ml.so.2.4.9
ln -s /usr/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4.9
ln -s /usr/lib/libopencv_photo.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_photo.so.2.4.9
ln -s /usr/lib/libopencv_stitching.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_stitching.so.2.4.9
ln -s /usr/lib/libopencv_superres.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_superres.so.2.4.9
ln -s /usr/lib/libopencv_tegra.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_tegra.so.2.4.9
ln -s /usr/lib/libopencv_video.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_video.so.2.4.9
ln -s /usr/lib/libopencv_videostab.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videostab.so.2.4.9
ln -s /usr/lib/libopencv_vstab.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_vstab.so.2.4.9
```

You can also get complaints about **libopencv_ocl**. This library does not exist in opencv4tegra. I managed to bypass this error by creating a dummy shared library containing no functions (but correctly compiled) and naming it libopencv_ocl.so.X.X.X and placing it in the directory you mentioned.

---

Originally posted by [marting](https://answers.ros.org/users/28111/marting/) with karma: 36 on 2016-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jetson_student_group](https://answers.ros.org/users/34099/jetson_student_group/) on 2018-03-12**:
hi, Thanks a lot for the solution. we encountered the same problem and followed your instruction accordingly. For the last step though, can you please guide us on how I can prepare a shared library?
Thanks a lot!